# Polynomial divisible by a prime $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, divisibility

Let $p$ be an odd prime number and $P(x)$ be a polynomial of integer coefficients such that $\deg(P(x)) \le p-2 $. Let $D_p$ be the set of positive integers that are not divisibile by $p$. It's known that $p|P(x)$ for every $ x\in D_p $. Prove or disprove that $p$ divide every coefficient of $P(x)$.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: It's own problem and i constructed it starting from my solution, witch I see it's the same of @ajotatxe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint*:

The equation $P(x)\equiv 0\pmod p$ has at most $p-2$ solutions in $\Bbb Z_p$.